# trouble of opening another class

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface, jcombobox

I have a problem about opening another class because i have a `JComboBox` that will contain the choices of class that i need to often so here is my code please check it .

```
package Patola;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class imagebut extends JFrame {
    // ImageIcon we = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ban.png"));
    // ImageIcon wer = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ba.png"));

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        imagebut w = new imagebut();
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        w.setSize(300, 300);
        w.setVisible(true);


    }
    String[] cent = {"Conversion", "Adv.Calculator"};
    JComboBox box = new JComboBox(cent);
    JButton bi = new JButton("Patola");

    public imagebut() {
        /* JButton converter = new JButton("Convertion");
        JButton advancecalc = new JButton("Adv.Calculator");
        JButton calc = new JButton("Calculator");
        JButton Multiplication = new JButton("Multiplication");
        JButton Looping = new JButton("Looping");
        JButton Calendar = new JButton("Calendar");
        JButton Remarks = new JButton("Remarks");
        JButton Average = new JButton("Average");
        JButton Magicsq = new JButton("Magic Square");*/


        //      JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("gif.gif")));   
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();


        box.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 25);
        bi.setBounds(40, 40, 80, 30);
        getContentPane().add(pan);
        //getContentPane().add(background);
        pan.add(box);
        pan.add(bi);
        /*
        background.add(box);
        background.add(bi);
         */


        /* background.add(converter);
        background.add(calc);
        background.add(advancecalc);
        background.add(Magicsq);
        background.add(Remarks);
        background.add(Calendar);
        background.add(Average);
        background.add(Looping);
        background.add(Multiplication);*/


        box.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {

                String s = (String) box.getSelectedItem();
                switch(s) 
                {
                        case "Convertion": new converter(); break;
                }
            }
        });



    }
}
```

So if I choose converter then click the button `patola` I needed to open this frame this is the another class I need to open .

```
package Patola;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class converter extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
        Container con=getContentPane();

        JTextField input=new JTextField("");
        JButton BMI=new JButton("B.M.I");
        JButton dollars=new JButton("Peso to Dollars");
        JButton euro=new JButton("Peso to Euros");
        JButton yen=new JButton("Peso to Yen");
        JButton c=new JButton("Celcius to Farenheit");
        JButton f=new JButton("Farenheit to Celcius");
        JButton m=new JButton("Miles to Kilometers");
        JButton km=new JButton("Kilometers to Miles");
                JTextField inch = new JTextField(15);
                JButton ok = new JButton("Okay");
                JLabel lab = new JLabel("Enter height to inches");
                JFrame fr = new JFrame();

                double a,b,d;



    public converter()
        {
    super("Super Converter");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    con.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    con.add(input);
    con.add(BMI);
    con.add(dollars);
    con.add(euro);
    con.add(yen);
    con.add(c);
    con.add(f);
    con.add(m);
    con.add(km);
    BMI.addActionListener(this);
    dollars.addActionListener(this);
    yen.addActionListener(this);
    euro.addActionListener(this);
    c.addActionListener(this);
    f.addActionListener(this);
    m.addActionListener(this);
    km.addActionListener(this);
        ok.addActionListener(this);
    setContentPane(con);

            fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                        fr.setVisible(false);
                                        fr.setSize(200,150);
                                        JPanel p = new JPanel();
                                        p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


                                        p.add(lab);
                                        p.add(inch);
                                        p.add(ok);
                                        fr.add(p);


            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {

                            {
                                try
                                {
                if(e.getSource()==BMI)
                                {
                    fr.setLocation(500,250);
                                        fr.setVisible(true);

                                }

                                 if(e.getSource() == ok)
                                       {

                                            a=Double.parseDouble(inch.getText());
                                            b=Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
                                            d=b/a;
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fr,"BMI: "+d);
                                            input.setText("");
                                            inch.setText("");
                                            fr.setVisible(false);
                                       }
                    else if(e.getSource()== dollars)
                                        {
                        double a,b,d;
                        a=44.63;
                        b=Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
                        d=b/a;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"$"+d);
                        input.setText("");
                                        }
                        else if(e.getSource()== yen)
                                                {
                        double a,b,d;
                        a=2.28;
                        b=Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
                        d=b*a;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"�"+d);
                        input.setText("");
                                                }
                                else if(e.getSource()== euro)
                                                                {
                        double a,b,d;
                        a=0.016;
                        b=Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
                        d=b*a;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"�"+d);
                        input.setText("");
                                                                }
                            else if(e.getSource()== c)
                                                        {
                        double a,b,d,f;
                        a=1.8;
                        f=32.0;
                        b=Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
                        d=((b*a)+f);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,d+"�F");
                        input.setText("");
                                                        }
                                                        else if(e.getSource()== f){
                        double a,b,d,g;
                        a=0.555555555555556;
                        g=32.0;
                        b=Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
                        d=(b-g)*a;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,d+"ºC");
                        input.setText("");}
                        else if(e.getSource()== m)
                                                {
                        double a,b,d,f;
                        a=1.60934;
                        b=Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
                        d=(b*a);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,d+"Kilometers");
                        input.setText("");
                                                }
                        else if(e.getSource()== km)
                                                {

                        double a,b,d,f;
                        a=0.621371;
                                                b=Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
                        d=(b*a);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,d+"miles");
                        input.setText("");

                                                }
                                             }
                                catch(NumberFormatException qwe)
                                {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exception Thread No value !");
                                }
                    }

                        }



            public static void main (String [] args)
                        {
                converter aFrame=new converter();
                aFrame.setSize(250,350);
                                aFrame.setLocation(500,250);
                                aFrame.pack();
                                aFrame.setVisible(true);


            }
}
```

Comment: Don't just dump your code. Analyze it, debug it, post only the relevant parts.

Comment: the problem is on the first part sir . the second class i post is already Okay . but in the first part if you look at my ActionEvent then i Open the new converter(); that handle the second class but if i click it nothing will appear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This `if(e.getSource().equals("Convertion"))` is not going to work. `e.getSource()` returns the object source of a the object firing the `ActionEvent`. Comparing that to a `String` will get you nowhere.
2. Sorry, I just *had* to point this out because it was bugging me. But what *is* "Convertion"? Is that even a word. Maybe you mean "Conversion"
3. Just add the `ActionListener` to your `JComboBox` instead

   ```
   box.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
           String s = (String)box.getSelectedItem();
           switch(s) {
               case "Convertion": new conveter(); break;
               case "Adv.Calculator": ...
           }
       }
   });
   ```
4. In your `converter` and probably all your other frame classes, `setVisible(true)` *after* adding all components.
5. Why even use multiple frames. See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/2587435). You might find a better, cleaner solution.
6. Swing apps should be run on the Event Dispatch Thread. You could do so by wrapping the inside of your `main` in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater...`. See more details at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
7. If you *don't* want to add the `ActionListener` to the `JComboBox` and the `JButton` instead, just put the `switch` inside the `actionPerformed`. There's not need to check the source of the `ActionEvent` becuase you are only registering that listener with one button.

Comment: switch(s) the netbeans said string in switch are not supported in -source 1.6 . what does it mean ?

Comment: It's pretty obvious what it means. It said it loud and clear. Either change your compiler to 1.7 or just use an `if` statement instead.

Comment: 1.7 compiler sir ? what is it sorry i am new about this .

Comment: Right click on your `project --> Project Properties`. Then in `Sources` set `Source/Binary` Format to `JDK 7`.

Comment: about this sir . i correctly do your number 3 option . but nothing appear i cant open my converter class

Comment: The frame should open when you select the item from the combobox. If you are having problems with switch statements, just use `if` statements.

Comment: in your pc sir it is runnning ?

Comment: I didn't test it. Also take out the `main` method in `converter`. You don't need it or anything in it.

Comment: i will take it out ? how sir ?

Comment: Highlight all of it with your mouse. Then press delete on your keyboard

Comment: i did already sir . i removed my main method in the converter but still not opening the converter

Comment: You chnaged the name in the combo box to conversion, so you need to change the swtch also. Also you need to set the frame visible(true), it's currently false.

Comment: what frame sir i need to set true . the frame in converter ? i am right ?

Comment: Look, how many frames do you have? Out of the two, which one has setVisible(false)

Comment: the converter sir . i mean sir how can i set it true just only setVisible(true); it didnt work sir . i dont have a main method to named my JFrame sir . i am confusing hahaha .

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$SmallAttributeSet.containsAttributes(StyleContext.java:973)
 at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$SmallAttributeSet.equals(StyleContext.java:852)
 at java.util.WeakHashMap.eq(WeakHashMap.java:343)
 at java.util.WeakHashMap.get(WeakHashMap.java:468)
 at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.get(Collections.java:2037)

Comment: It works for me. You need to change "Contertion" in your switch to "Conversion" Then in the `converter` change `setVisible(false)`to `true`. Put the setVisible _after_ you finish adding all the components.

Comment: **Don't** create a `new Converter()` in your `converter` constructor. That is probably why you are getting `stackoverflow`

Comment: i see now i get It the only problem to me is the "Conversion" thanks sir godbless :)

Comment: Also your `converter` is _already_ a `JFrame`. You don't need to create another `JFrame`